# Python packaging LegacyVersion

Tags: python, packaging

As denoted here https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/changelog.html since `22.0` there is no more `LegacyVersion` in the Python module `packaging`.

With e.g. 21.3 the following was possible

```
from packaging import version
version.parse('-1.-1.-1')
```

That would return an object `<LegacyVersion('-1.-1.-1')>` and this logic is implemented in my code base. In my program it reflects the fact that the version of something is unknown.
But that won't work anymore since `22.0`. It throws an error that the version number was illegal.

Doing `version.parse('0.0.0')` returns an object `<Version('0.0.0')>`. But I don't want to follow that approach, since it is currently not clear if at any time we would have to have a `0.0.0` for a specific purpose in the future.

Does somebody know how to express "version unknown" with packaging `23.1`? It is required that the "version unknown" is comparable with normal objects of type `Version` so that `<unknown version>` is lower than `<Version('0.0.0')>`!